# CString.getbuffer() giving compiling error in VC++6.0 but successfully compiling in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-c++

I am new at VC++. I have the code developed in VC++ 6.0
Now i have opened it in Visual Studio 2005 and it is compiling successfully. But on compiling it in Visual Studio 6.0 envnt it is throwing error saying "getBuffer() can not call with 0 parameters"
Why is it compiling in visual studio 2005 not in visual studio 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the failing/working code it's impossible to be definitive, but I would trust Visual Studio 2005 over Visual C++ 6.0 any day of the week.

Visual C++ 6.0 is really showing its age (it's no longer supported by Microsoft, for one thing) - VC++ v8.0 (in VS2005) is a much better compiler.